# Objective C: Popover Dismissed Without Opening the File to Another App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uidocumentinteraction

In the app that I am working I have files to be downloaded from a server and store it locally in the app's sandbox, then open it in iBooks using `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

I have done it all the downloading, saving, and opening it to iBooks. But, there are times that when I download a file then open it to iBooks it is not implementing, iBooks is not opening but the delgates are read from `willBeginSendingToApplication:` to `didEndSendingToApplication:` to `documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu:` (i put logs on it to check). Then if I restart the app it opens, then not open again, it is not consistent. What could be the problem?

Here my code for opening it to iBooks:

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath1];
        DocController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
        DocController.delegate = self;
        [DocController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:openIt.frame inView:menu animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

With UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate added in your .h, you can add this function :

```
- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:        (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller
{
    return self;  //return the controller who open the doc
}
```